# Getting pages list by taxonomy in wordpress custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have terms and conditions which are used in different pages. Now I want to list the pages against the term and condition. so I want to get pages of specific terms and conditions (taxonomy). Your kind help is required. I went through some blogs and I get this.

```
$product_page_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'child_of' => $post_id,
                        'taxonomy' => 'term-condition',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'term' => 'ID'
                    );

                    $product_pages = new WP_Query($product_page_args);
                    foreach ($product_pages as $product_page){  
                        echo $product_page->post_title;
                    }
```

Comment: What do you get in the `$product_page`?

Answer (score 0):

I will share my code for something quite similar. My code lists all pages for a given taxonomy on a taxonomy template: `website.com/{taxonomy-slug}/{term-slug}`.

```
$taxonomy = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$tax_term = get_query_var( 'term' );

// get all post types for tax term
$posts_list = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $tax_term,
        ),
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'nopaging' => true
));
```

In your case this would be something like this:

```
$posts_list = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'term-condition',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'ID',
        ),
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'nopaging' => true
));
```

Given that 'ID' is a term for the taxonomy 'term-condition'. If so, I would reconsider this name, because it is easy to confuse with ID as a property of post objects.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I am new to wordpress.. so I am a little confuse about the terms, will it contain the value or the field name?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. `$taxonomy` will contain the name and `$tax_term` will contain the value. So as an example; `$taxonomy` could be 'industry' and `$tax_term` could then be 'Agriculture'